# Four Directions #15 - Where and what am I?

Tags: knowledge, geography

> To the North-West <s>there are four larger</s> is the fifth largest.
>   To the North-East this small place has nine different kinds of ethnicity.
>   To the South-West <s>there are six larger</s> is the seventh largest.
>   To the South-East this place is only three times larger than the water within.
>   You will find me where three <s>become one</s> meet at one point.
>   Where am I?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are

> [Mount Sabyinyo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mount_Sabyinyo)

To the North-West is the fifth largest.

> Chad to the northwest is the [5th largest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_African_countries_by_area) country in Africa.

To the North-East this small place has nine different kinds of ethnicity.

> This is Eritrea, as found by Omega Krypton

To the South-West is the seventh largest.

> Angola to the southwest is the 7th largest country in Africa.

To the South-East this place is only three times larger than the water within.

> Malawi to the southeast is approximately 3x larger than the [eponymous lake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lake_Malawi).

You will find me where three become one.

> Mount Sabyinyo's summit marks the point where the borders of Rwanda, Uganda and DR Congo meet.

Comment: You have all of the clues correct, but the final location is slightly off. Have amended the clue to help

Comment: @AHKieran Thanks! I think this time I have it :)

Answer (score 3):

The answer is

> South Sudan?

North-West:

> Four larger= Chad, Nigeria, Niger, Algeria

North-East:

> Eritrea, the nine ethnic groups are Afar, Bilen, Hidarb, Kunama, Nara, Rashaida, Saho, Tigre, and Tigrina

South-West:

> Six larger= DR Congo, Namibia, Angola, Zambia, South Africa?, last one???

South-East:

> Uganda? Although the statistics say that the water area is just about 15% of the total country area, it seems a lot larger than that.

Three become one:

> Somewhat related from independence from Sudan?

Comment: Why are you counting those specific countries to the northwest? It seems like there are a couple of other roughly equally plausible candidates.

Comment: Just as accurate as possible... I know there are a lot more choices, just choosing the best ones

Comment: You have one answer correct, I think you've misunderstood the meaning of the "larger" lines. Will update